# How can I get C/C++ context-sensitive completion with Company?

Tags: completion, company-mode, c++, semantic-mode

[`Semantic`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Semantic.html) *seems* to be able to do this, but I cannot get it to work as I would expect it to.  For example, if I `#include "Type.h"` and declare `Type t`, using `semantic-complete-analyze-inline` when point is after `t.` consistently gives me the error

> Cannot find types for `Type t'

instead of giving me all of the public (or otherwise appropriate) members of `t`.

How can I get the result I'm looking for here?  Ideally, how can I use whatever Semantic might provide as a backend for Company?

Comment: Are you sure Type.h exists, is being found, and declares the type Type? If I make Type.h and Type.cpp in the same directory with Type.h declaring a class `Type` with fields `int foo` and `char bar`, semantic and company work out of the box.

Comment: Have you verified if `company-backends` variable has `company-semantic` in its list?  If not, you'll want to add prepend it to the first of the list so that it's searched first

Comment: Interestingly, it works with the minimal example I describe.  (Unfortunately I really can't give the actual use case, but it shouldn't matter.)  Is there any way I can force Semantic to reparse everything?

Comment: @JDavidSmith How can I ensure it is being found?  The project I'm actually working with is very complex in its build structure.

Comment: @cheezy `company-semantic` is in `company-backends`; thanks :)

Comment: Another option is using Company with Clang, [using this setup](http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html#sec-5).

Comment: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/474/using-emacs-as-a-full-featured-c-c-ide might help (http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/474/using-emacs-as-a-full-featured-c-c-ide#comment5549_644 is my preferred solution)

Comment: See also the related post: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/801/how-to-get-intelligent-auto-completion-in-c

Comment: @GuillaumePapin I always overlooked `irony-mode` – not too sure why. If I can get it to work, I'll be tempted to close this as a duplicate.  It doesn't give a solution to work with Semantic, but it gives a solution that achieves the same goal (or at least appears to).  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to follow the tutorial [here](http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html#sec-2) and setup `company-clang` to get better candidates.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [irony-mode](https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode) with [company-irony](https://github.com/Sarcasm/company-irony) for completion instead of semantic as semantic is generally too slow and simplistic - ie. it often doesn't offer completions when you would think it should.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to initialize CEDET and ede

```el
(global-ede-mode 1)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semanticdb-minor-mode 1)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode 1)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode 1)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-highlight-func-mode 1)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-idle-summary-mode t)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-idle-completions-mode t)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-srecode-minor-mode t)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-decoration-mode t)
(semantic-mode) ;; Active le mode semantic
(require 'stickyfunc-enhance) ;; multilines concatene dans la header line
(require 'cedet-cscope)

(require 'ecb)
(ede-cpp-root-project "projName"
                  :name "projName Project"
                  :file "~/workspaces/projName/proj.txt" ;; an arbitrary file
                  :include-path '("/src/main/src"
                                  "/src/main/include"
                                  "/src/test/src"
                                  "/src/test/include"
                                  ... )
                  :system-include-path '("/usr/include/ ~/workspaces/install/proj3/lib/ /usr/include/boost/")
                  :spp-table '(("isUnix" . "") ("BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK" . "")))
;; cedet semantic
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c-mode t)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c++-mode t)
;; You can add this to improve the parse of macro-heavy code:
(require 'semantic/bovine/c)
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/stddef.h")
```

then you can use company-c-headers (https://github.com/randomphrase/company-c-headers)

```el
(require 'company-c-headers)
     (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-c-headers)
     (add-to-list 'company-c-headers-path-system "/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/ /home/me/DEPEDENCIES/LIBXX/lib/ /home/me/DEPEDENCIES/LIBYY/lib /usr/include/boost/"))
```