# Show constructor arguments for c++

Tags: package, c++, arguments

Is there a package that can tell me the arguments for c++ constructor?

```
class T1 {
    public:
        T1(int x, int y);
};

T1::T1(int x, int y) {
    std::cout << x+y << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    T1 h1(5, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

For example when I write `T1 h1(` it informs me the constructor takes int x and int y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [rtags](https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags). An introduction is available at Vx Labs, *[Step-by-step guide to C++ navigation and completion with Emacs and the Clang-based rtags](https://vxlabs.com/2016/04/11/step-by-step-guide-to-c-navigation-and-completion-with-emacs-and-the-clang-based-rtags/)*. The introduction presents an rtags installation via the ELPA packaging system, noting a dependency on the Debian/Ubuntu libclang 'dev package (e.g  `libclang-3.6-dev` in Ubuntu 14.04) and also mentions the support for [company-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompanyMode) in rtags.

Some more information about company-mode, elsewhere at the Emacs Stack Exchange: *[How can I get C/C++ context-sensitive completion with Company?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3359/how-can-i-get-c-c-context-sensitive-completion-with-company)*

Alternately, of course there's cscope and similar - at the Emacs Wiki, some information/advice, [CScopeAndEmacs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CScopeAndEmacs)